# PivotTables multiple data source

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I am trying to create a PivotTable to generate a weekly report.
Basically I get a report every week with the same fields and I would like to add this as a source to the PivotTable.

Columns on the source are `Customer`, `City`, `Agent status`.

My goal is to have a PivotTable to generate the data and see the progress of our agent deployment per week.
Currently the only way I found was to put all the data in a single sheet and create the pivot from there. Adding a extra column with date. Since the report is 22k rows each week.

Excel version 2010

Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the description 2010

Comment: Yes but it does not allow me to filter the output by Agent Status. 
Example, single worksheet gives me Customer, then city then values for each agent status.
With multiple consolidation this does not happen, the filter has to be done manually and progress is not clear, unless I do 2 separate reports.

Comment: Look into using PowerQuery to automate this. can use it to pull in both tables, add the date column and dump into a single table for use with a pivot table.

Comment: How is the report you receive structured?

Comment: @guitarthrower thanks for the tip. It helped a lot already.

Comment: @soulus101, the structure is like in the description with an additiobn of system. For each system the agent status can have 3 status. But as guitarthrower mentioned powergrid it works as merging everything into a single sheet and using pivot table to get the data by date and see the progress.